# Unable to configure a Proxy for API Calls With Angular CLI

Tags: javascript, angular, proxy

I have been trying to create a proxy for an API call using Angular CLI for hours. However, it is not working.

My frontend development serve runs on localhost:4200 and I'm trying to make an API call to a public link of this format: http://url.com/api/obj/1

In Angular2 project, I have a file:
proxy.conf.json

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": "true",
    "pathRewrite": {"^/api": ""}
  }
}
```

and under Angular2 project package.json file,I changed start procedure to "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"

When I run my mac terminal with "npm start", the webpack is compiled successfully. However, I do not see any proxy created message during compilation.

From my Angular ts file, I send a request method to call the API.

```js
 private _url: string = "http://url/api/obj/1";
 
    constructor(private _http: Http){}
    getmethod(){
      return this._http.get(this._url)
        .map((response:Response) => response.json());  
    }
```

However, the chrome console throws the following error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://url.com/api/obj/1. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

Did I miss out any important information?Please help! Thanks.

Comment: Add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * at server end. probably your server is not allowing it to access from other domain.

Comment: Hi, I can't modify the server because it's an external API.